# Creating an Active Directory domain across regions to attach virtual machines to

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement to create two virtual machines in different Azure regions, in addition to this they both need to be in the same Active Directory domain.

I would ideally like to do this using Azure Active Directory, however, I have a horrible suspicion that I would need to create a domain controller on its own dedicated virtual machine, assuming that this is correct, my follow on question is how I 'Stretch' the domain across regions, I suspect that if I make the domain controller available across regions via vnet peering, this might work ?.

Can someone confirm that I am on the right track here?

Comment: Hi @ChrisAdkin, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   You can use the **‘Azure Active Directory Domain Services’** feature to set up your domain and AD services in Azure. With this feature, when you `create an Azure ADDS managed domain, you can define a unique namespace, i.e., your domain name with which you want to identify, or domain join your systems with. Once the managed domain is setup, two Windows Server Domain Controllers are setup and then deployed into your selected Azure region`.

•   Also, **you don't need to manage, configure, or update these DCs. The Azure platform handles the DCs as part of the managed domain, including backups and encryption at rest using Azure Disk Encryption. Please do take cognizance that you can expand a managed domain to have more than one replica set per Azure AD tenant. Replica sets can be added to any peered virtual network in any Azure region that supports Azure AD DS. Additional replica sets in different Azure regions provide geographical disaster recovery for legacy applications if an Azure region goes offline**.

•   Also, do consider that **Azure AD DS includes multiple domain controllers**, which provide **high availability for your managed domain**. This `high availability guarantees service uptime and resilience to failures`. In regions that support Azure Availability Zones, these domain controllers are also **distributed across zones for additional resiliency**. Replica sets can also be used to provide geographical disaster recovery for legacy applications if an Azure region goes offline.

For more information, kindly refer to the documentation below regarding Azure AD Domain services: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#how-does-azure-ad-ds-work